# How to create custom event listener in node.js (express.js)?

Tags: events, node.js

I have a giant function with a lot of nested callbacks.  I want to make it cleaner and easier to handle.  So, I'm thinking of using custom event listeners

Like, when a function is done, in the callback, instead of putting a chunk of code, it just emits an event, and then the listener will run.

So, how to do that in node.js?  I am still looking for a good example to guide me through.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903154/how-do-i-avoid-deeply-nested-code-in-node-js?

Comment: Thanks. I will try. which one is the better one?

Comment: The first one is most related to your problem.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but how about `async.js` instead of event listeners?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to create an [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/events.html#events.EventEmitter) object, and call `emit()` on it.

Answer (score 29):

You can set events like this

```
app.on('event:user_created', callback);
```

Then you can emit them

```
app.emit('event:user_created', data);
```

*express.js* uses `EventEmitter`.

Comment: It's actually that `app` extends `EventEmitter` in **connect** framework which **express** extends . [connect.js@68](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/connect.js#L68) `utils.merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);`

Comment: So the express `app` can act as an app-wide dispatch

Comment: will this take an err object - app.emit('event:foo', err, data) - for instance if we're returning the result of a database query?

Comment: how would you call this from a route file? How do you get access to app?

Comment: I don't think this works anymore with express.js 4. All I get when I call app.emit() is an undefined is not a function error

Comment: in Express.js you can do `req.app.emit(...)`. Because every request object has a reference of the app

Answer (score 6):

I just came across this question, I'd like to chip in my 2 cents, specifically responding to Luis.

In Express, if you want the 'app' instance to listen for a custom event you would do something like:

```
app.on('testEvent', function () {
  return console.log('responded to testEvent');
});

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  app.emit('testEvent');
  return res.status(200).end();
});
```

Then when that route is hit, you'd see the response in the console. Of course you can implement this as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The Node.js "events" module and the "EventEmitter" module facilitates communication between objects in Node. The EventEmitter module is at the core of Node's asynchronous event-driven architecture. Here is how you can create custom events and emit them:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();

//Event Listener
const EventListenerFunc = () => {
 console.log('an event occurred!');
}

//Registering the event with the listener
myEmitter.on('eventName', EventListenerFunc);

//Emitting the event 
myEmitter.emit('eventName');
```