# What is "callback hell" and how and why does RX solve it?

Tags: javascript, callback, language-lawyer, reactive-programming, rxjs

Can someone give a clear definition together with a simple example that explains what is a "callback hell" for someone who does not know JavaScript and node.js ?

When (in what kind of settings) does the "callback hell problem" occur?

Why does it occur?

Is "callback hell" always related to asynchronous computations?

Or can "callback hell" occur also in a single threaded application?

I took the Reactive Course at Coursera and Erik Meijer said in one of his lectures that RX solves the problem of "callback hell". I asked what is a "callback hell" on the Coursera forum but I got no clear answer.

After explaining "callback hell" on a simple example, could you also show how RX solves the "callback hell problem" on that simple example?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

### 1) What is a "callback hell" for someone who does not know javascript and node.js ?

This other question has some examples of Javascript callback hell: [How to avoid long nesting of asynchronous functions in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234619/how-to-avoid-long-nesting-of-asynchronous-functions-in-node-js)

The problem in Javascript is that the only way to "freeze" a computation and have the "rest of it" execute latter (asynchronously) is to put "the rest of it" inside a callback.

For example, say I want to run code that looks like this:

```
x = getData();
y = getMoreData(x);
z = getMoreData(y);
...
```

What happens if now I want to make the getData functions asynchronous, meaning that I get a chance to run some other code while I am waiting for them to return their values? In Javascript, the only way would be to rewrite everything that touches an async computation using [continuation passing style](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FContinuation-passing_style):

```
getData(function(x){
    getMoreData(x, function(y){
        getMoreData(y, function(z){ 
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

I don't think I need to convince anyone that this version is uglier than the previous one. :-)

### 2) When (in what kind of settings) does the "callback hell problem" occur?

When you have lots of callback functions in your code! It gets harder to work with them the more of them you have in your code and it gets particularly bad when you need to do loops, try-catch blocks and things like that.

For example, as far as I know, in JavaScript the only way to execute a series of asynchronous functions where one is run after the previous returns is using a recursive function. You can't use a for loop.

```
// we would like to write the following
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    doSomething(i);
}
blah();
```

Instead, we might need to end up writing:

```
function loop(i, onDone){
    if(i >= 10){
        onDone()
    }else{
        doSomething(i, function(){
            loop(i+1, onDone);
        });
     }
}
loop(0, function(){
    blah();
});

//ugh!
```

The number of questions we get here on StackOverflow asking how to do this kind of thing is a testament to how confusing it is :)

### 3) Why does it occur ?

It occurs because in JavaScript the only way to delay a computation so that it runs after the asynchronous call returns is to put the delayed code inside a callback function. You cannot delay code that was written in traditional synchronous style so you end up with nested callbacks everywhere.

### 4) Or can "callback hell" occur also in a single threaded application?

Asynchronous programming has to do with concurrency while a threads have to do with parallelism. The two concepts are actually not the same thing.

You can still have concurrent code in a single threaded context. In fact, JavaScript, the queen of callback hell, is single threaded.

[What is the difference between concurrency and parallelism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/concurrency-vs-parallelism-what-is-the-difference#1050257)

### 5) could you please also show how RX solves the "callback hell problem" on that simple example.

I don't know anything about RX in particular, but usually this problem gets solved by adding native support for asynchronous computation in the programming language. The implementations can vary and include: async, generators, coroutines, and callcc.

In Python we can implement that previous loop example with something along the lines of:

```
def myLoop():
    for i in range(10):
        doSomething(i)
        yield

myGen = myLoop()
```

This is not the full code but the idea is that the "yield" pauses our for loop until someone calls myGen.next(). The important thing is that we could still write the code using a for loop, without needing to turn out logic "inside out" like we had to do in that recursive `loop` function.

Comment: So callback hell can only occur in an async setting? If my code is  fully sychronous (ie. no concurrency) then "callback hell"  can not occur if I understand your answer correctly, is that right?

Comment: Callback hell has more to do with how annoying it is to code using continuation passing style. Theroretically you could still rewrite all your functions using CPS style even for a regular program (the wikipedia article has some examples) but, for good reason, most people dont do that. Usually we only use continuation passing style if we are forced to, which is the case for Javascript async programming.

Comment: btw, I googled for the reactive extensions and I am getting the impression that they are more similar to a Promise library and not a language extension  introducing async syntax. Promises help deal with the callback nesting and with the exception handling but they arent as neat as the syntax extensions. The for loop is still annoying to code and you still need to translate code from the synchronous style to the promise style.

Comment: I should clarify how RX generally does a better job. RX is declarative. You can declare how the program will respond to events when they later occur without affecting any other program logic. This allows you to separate main loop code from event handling code. You can easily handle details like async event ordering that are a nightmare when using state variables. I found RX was the cleanest implementation to perform a new network request after 3 network responses returned or to error handle the whole chain if one does not return. Then it can reset itself and wait for the same 3 events.

Comment: One more related comment: RX is basically the continuation monad, which relates to CPS if I am not mistaken, this might also explain how/why RX is good for the callback/hell problem.

Comment: In your point 4) you wrote: "Asynchronous programming has to do with concurrency while a single-thread has to do with parallelism". I had trouble wrapping my head around this, did you mean to write: "(...) a multi-thread has to do with parallelism"?

Answer (score 34):

To address the question of how Rx solves *callback hell*:

First let's describe callback hell again.

Imagine a case were we must do http to get three resources - person, planet and galaxy. Our objective is to find the galaxy the person lives in. First we must get the person, then the planet, then the galaxy. That's three callbacks for three asynchronous operations.

```
getPerson(person => { 
   getPlanet(person, (planet) => {
       getGalaxy(planet, (galaxy) => {
           console.log(galaxy);
       });
   });
});
```

Each callback is nested. Each inner callback is dependent on its parent. This leads to the "pyramid of doom" style of *callback hell*. The code looks like a > sign.

To solve this in RxJs you could do something like so:

```
getPerson()
  .map(person => getPlanet(person))
  .map(planet => getGalaxy(planet))
  .mergeAll()
  .subscribe(galaxy => console.log(galaxy));
```

With the `mergeMap` AKA `flatMap` operator you could make it more succinct:

```
getPerson()
  .mergeMap(person => getPlanet(person))
  .mergeMap(planet => getGalaxy(planet))
  .subscribe(galaxy => console.log(galaxy));
```

As you can see, the code is flattened and contains a single chain of function calls. We have no "pyramid of doom".

Hence, callback hell is avoided.

In case you were wondering, *promises* are another way to avoid callback hell, but promises are *eager*, not *lazy* like observables and (generally speaking) you cannot cancel them as easily.

Comment: I'm not a JS developer , but this is easy explanation

Comment: This is the best explanation.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "promises are eager, not lazy"?

Comment: Observables only execute when they have at least one subscriber. So you can compose them in advance and execute later by subscribing. Promises are executed when the interpreter sees the declaration of the promise.

Answer (score 31):

Just answer the question: could you please also show how RX solves the "callback hell problem" on that simple example?

The magic is `flatMap`. We can write the following code in Rx for @hugomg's example:

```
def getData() = Observable[X]
getData().flatMap(x -> Observable[Y])
         .flatMap(y -> Observable[Z])
         .map(z -> ...)...
```

It's like you are writing some synchronous FP codes, but actually you can make them asynchronous by `Scheduler`.

Answer (score 15):

Callback hell is any code where the use of function callbacks in async code becomes obscure or difficult to follow. Generally, when there is more than one level of indirection, code using callbacks can become harder to follow, harder to refactor, and harder to test. A code smell is multiple levels of indentation due to passing multiple layers of function literals.

This often happens when behaviour has dependencies, i.e. when A must happen before B must happen before C. Then you get code like this:

```
a({
    parameter : someParameter,
    callback : function() {
        b({
             parameter : someOtherParameter,
             callback : function({
                 c(yetAnotherParameter)
        })
    }
});
```

If you have lots of behavioural dependencies in your code like this, it can get troublesome fast. Especially if it branches...

```
a({
    parameter : someParameter,
    callback : function(status) {
        if (status == states.SUCCESS) {
          b(function(status) {
              if (status == states.SUCCESS) {
                 c(function(status){
                     if (status == states.SUCCESS) {
                         // Not an exaggeration. I have seen
                         // code that looks like this regularly.
                     }
                 });
              }
          });
        } elseif (status == states.PENDING {
          ...
        }
    }
});
```

This won't do. How can we make asynchronous code execute in a determined order without having to pass all these callbacks around?

RX is short for 'reactive extensions'. I haven't used it, but Googling suggests it's an event-based framework, which makes sense. **Events are a common pattern to make code execute in order without creating brittle coupling**. You can make C listen to the event 'bFinished' which only happens after B is called listening to 'aFinished'. You can then easily add extra steps or extend this kind of behaviour, and can **easily test** that your code executes in order by merely broadcasting events in your test case.

Answer (score 3):

Call back hell means you are inside of a callback of inside another callback and it goes to nth call until your needs not fullfiled.

Let's understand through an example of fake ajax call by using set timeout API, lets assume we have a recipe API, we need to download all recipe.

```
<body>
    <script>
        function getRecipe(){
            setTimeout(()=>{
                const recipeId = [83938, 73838, 7638];
                console.log(recipeId);
            }, 1500);
        }
        getRecipe();
    </script>
</body>
```

In the above example after 1.5 sec when timer expires inside code of call back will execute, in other words, through our fake ajax call all recipe will downloaded from the server. Now we need to download a particular recipe data.

```
<body>
    <script>
        function getRecipe(){
            setTimeout(()=>{
                const recipeId = [83938, 73838, 7638];
                console.log(recipeId);
                setTimeout(id=>{
                    const recipe = {title:'Fresh Apple Juice', publisher:'Suru'};
                    console.log(`${id}: ${recipe.title}`);
                }, 1500, recipeId[2])
            }, 1500);
        }
        getRecipe();
    </script>
</body>
```

To download a particular recipe data we wrote code inside of our first callback and passed recipe Id.

Now let's say we need to download all the recipes of the same publisher of the recipe which id is 7638.

```
<body>
    <script>
        function getRecipe(){
            setTimeout(()=>{
                const recipeId = [83938, 73838, 7638];
                console.log(recipeId);
                setTimeout(id=>{
                    const recipe = {title:'Fresh Apple Juice', publisher:'Suru'};
                    console.log(`${id}: ${recipe.title}`);
                    setTimeout(publisher=>{
                        const recipe2 = {title:'Fresh Apple Pie', publisher:'Suru'};
                        console.log(recipe2);
                    }, 1500, recipe.publisher);
                }, 1500, recipeId[2])
            }, 1500);
        }
        getRecipe();
    </script>
</body>
```

To full-fill our needs which is to download all the recipes of publisher name suru, we wrote code inside of our second call back. It is clear we wrote a callback chain which is called callback hell.

If you want to avoid callback hell, you can use Promise, which is js es6 feature, each promise takes a callback which is called when a promise is full-filled. promise callback has two options either it is resolved or reject. Suppose your API call is successful you can call resolve and pass data through the **resolve**, you can get this data by using **then()**. But if your API failed you can use reject, use **catch** to catch the error. Remember a promise always use **then** for resolve and **catch** for reject

Let's solve the previous callback hell problem using a promise.

```
<body>
    <script>

        const getIds = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                const downloadSuccessfull = true;
                const recipeId = [83938, 73838, 7638];
                if(downloadSuccessfull){
                    resolve(recipeId);
                }else{
                    reject('download failed 404');
                }
            }, 1500);
        });

        getIds.then(IDs=>{
            console.log(IDs);
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Now download particular recipe:

```
<body>
    <script>
        const getIds = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                const downloadSuccessfull = true;
                const recipeId = [83938, 73838, 7638];
                if(downloadSuccessfull){
                    resolve(recipeId);
                }else{
                    reject('download failed 404');
                }
            }, 1500);
        });

        const getRecipe = recID => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                setTimeout(id => {
                    const downloadSuccessfull = true;
                    if (downloadSuccessfull){
                        const recipe = {title:'Fresh Apple Juice', publisher:'Suru'};
                        resolve(`${id}: ${recipe.title}`);
                    }else{
                        reject(`${id}: recipe download failed 404`);
                    }

                }, 1500, recID)
            })
        }
        getIds.then(IDs=>{
            console.log(IDs);
            return getRecipe(IDs[2]);
        }).
        then(recipe =>{
            console.log(recipe);
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Now we can write another method call **allRecipeOfAPublisher** like getRecipe which will also return a promise, and we can write another then() to receive resolve promise for allRecipeOfAPublisher, I hope at this point you can do it by yourself.

So we learned how to construct and consumed promises, now let's make consuming a promise easier by using async/await which is introduced in es8.

```
<body>
    <script>

        const getIds = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                const downloadSuccessfull = true;
                const recipeId = [83938, 73838, 7638];
                if(downloadSuccessfull){
                    resolve(recipeId);
                }else{
                    reject('download failed 404');
                }
            }, 1500);
        });

        const getRecipe = recID => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                setTimeout(id => {
                    const downloadSuccessfull = true;
                    if (downloadSuccessfull){
                        const recipe = {title:'Fresh Apple Juice', publisher:'Suru'};
                        resolve(`${id}: ${recipe.title}`);
                    }else{
                        reject(`${id}: recipe download failed 404`);
                    }

                }, 1500, recID)
            })
        }

        async function getRecipesAw(){
            const IDs = await getIds;
            console.log(IDs);
            const recipe = await getRecipe(IDs[2]);
            console.log(recipe);
        }

        getRecipesAw();
    </script>
</body>
```

In the above example, we used an async function because it will run in the background, inside async function we used **await** keyword before each method which returns or is a promise because to wait on that position until that promise fulfilled, in other words in the bellow codes until getIds completed resolved or reject program will stop executing codes bellow that line when IDs returned then we again called getRecipe() function with a id and waited by using await keyword until data returned. So this is how finally we recovered from the callback hell.

```
  async function getRecipesAw(){
            const IDs = await getIds;
            console.log(IDs);
            const recipe = await getRecipe(IDs[2]);
            console.log(recipe);
        }
```

To use await we will need a async function, we can return a promise so use then for resolve promise and cath for reject promise

from the above example:

```
 async function getRecipesAw(){
            const IDs = await getIds;
            const recipe = await getRecipe(IDs[2]);
            return recipe;
        }

        getRecipesAw().then(result=>{
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way Callback hell can be avoided is to use FRP which is an "enhanced version" of RX.

I started to use FRP recently because I have found a good implementation of it called `Sodium` ( http://sodium.nz/ ).

A typical code looks like this ( Scala.js ) :

```
def render: Unit => VdomElement = { _ =>
  <.div(
    <.hr,
    <.h2("Note Selector"),
    <.hr,
    <.br,
    noteSelectorTable.comp(),
    NoteCreatorWidget().createNewNoteButton.comp(),
    NoteEditorWidget(selectedNote.updates()).comp(),
    <.hr,
    <.br
  )
}
```

`selectedNote.updates()` is a `Stream` which fires if `selectedNode` (which is a `Cell`) changes, the `NodeEditorWidget` then updates correspondingly.

So, depending on the content of the `selectedNode` `Cell`, the currently edited `Note` will change.

This code avoids Callback-s entirely, almost, Cacllback-s are pushed to the "outer layer"/"surface" of the app, where the state handling logic interfaces with the external world. There are no Callbacks needed to propagate data within the internal state handling logic (which implements a state machine).

The full source code is [here](http://github.com/jhegedus42/irie/blob/14240c5c46cea458cf3fc8f0f8996b3f6c2f41eb/modules/client/src/main/scala/client/ui/compositeWidgets/note/NoteCreateReadUpdateWidget.scala#L63-L63)

The code snippet above corrosponds to the following simple Create / Display / Update example :

[image]

This code also sends updates to the server, so changes to the updated Entities are saved to the server automatically.

All the event handling is taken care by using `Stream`s and `Cell`s. These are FRP concepts. Callbacks are only needed where the FRP logic interfaces with the external world, such as user input, editing text, pressing a button, AJAX call returns.

Data flow is explicitly described, in a declarative manner using FRP (implemented by the Sodium library), so no event handling / callback logic is needed to describe data flow.

FRP (which is a more "strict" version of RX) is a way to describe a data flow graph, which can contain nodes that contain state. Events trigger state changes in the state containing nodes (called `Cell`s).

Sodium is a higher order FRP library, meaning that using the `flatMap`/`switch` primitive one can rearrange the data flow graph at runtime.

I recommend to have a look into the [Sodium book](https://livebook.manning.com/book/functional-reactive-programming/about-this-book/), it explains in detail how FRP gets rid of all Callbacks which are not essential for describing dataflow logic that has to do with updating the applications state in response to some external stimuli.

Using FRP, only those Callbacks need to be kept which describe interaction with the external world. In other words, the dataflow is described in a functional / declarative manner when one uses an FRP framework (such as Sodium), or when one uses an "FRP like" framework (such as RX).

Sodium is also available for Javascript/Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** Demonstrated callback hell

**Solutions:**

1: with `.then()`

2: with `async` `await`

```js
// Issue: Callback Hell
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(' Callback hell... 1')
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(' Callback hell... 2')
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(' Callback hell... 3')
        }, 500)
    }, 500)
}, 500)

// Delay Promise based function 
const delay = (ms) => new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

// Solution #1: Then
delay(2000).then( res => {
   console.log('↩️ Then callback... 1')
   return delay(2000)
}).then( res => {
   console.log('↩️ Then callback... 2')
   return delay(2000)   
 }).then( res => {
  console.log('↩️ Then callback... 3')
})

// Solution #2: Async Await 
async function asyncFunc() {
   await delay(7000)
   console.log('⏳ await callback... 1')
   await delay(2000)
   console.log('⏳ await callback... 2')
}
asyncFunc()
```

Answer (score -4):

Use jazz.js
https://github.com/Javanile/Jazz.js

it simplify like this:

```
    // run sequential task chained
    jj.script([
        // first task
        function(next) {
            // at end of this process 'next' point to second task and run it 
            callAsyncProcess1(next);
        },
      // second task
      function(next) {
        // at end of this process 'next' point to thirt task and run it 
        callAsyncProcess2(next);
      },
      // thirt task
      function(next) {
        // at end of this process 'next' point to (if have) 
        callAsyncProcess3(next);
      },
    ]);
```

Comment: consider ultra-compact like this https://github.com/Javanile/Jazz.js/wiki/Script-showcase

Answer (score -4):

"Callback hell," also known as "pyramid of doom" or "callback pyramid," refers to the situation in asynchronous programming where code becomes difficult to read and maintain due to the nesting of multiple callback functions. This typically occurs when dealing with asynchronous operations, such as I/O operations or network requests, in languages that use callbacks for handling asynchronous tasks.

In languages like JavaScript, which is often used for asynchronous programming, callbacks are commonly used to handle asynchronous tasks. Here's an example of callback hell in JavaScript:

```js
asyncOperation1(function(result1) {
  asyncOperation2(result1, function(result2) {
    asyncOperation3(result2, function(result3) {
      // ... and so on
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see, as more asynchronous operations are added, the code becomes deeply nested and harder to read. This structure makes it challenging to understand the flow of the program and introduces maintenance issues.

Reactive Extensions (Rx) is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs using observable sequences. Rx provides a way to handle asynchronous operations in a more concise and readable manner, helping to alleviate callback hell. Instead of dealing with nested callbacks, Rx allows you to use operators to compose and transform sequences of asynchronous events.

With Rx, you can rewrite the previous example using observable sequences:

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(asyncOperation1());

source
  .flatMap(result1 => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(asyncOperation2(result1)))
  .flatMap(result2 => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(asyncOperation3(result2)))
  .subscribe(result3 => {
    // Handle the final result
  });
```

In this example, the flatMap operator is used to flatten the nested structure, making the code more linear and easier to understand. The reactive programming paradigm in Rx promotes a more declarative and functional style, which can lead to more maintainable code for handling asynchronous operations. The use of operators allows developers to express complex asynchronous workflows more succinctly and with better composability.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Answer (score -6):

If you don't have a knowledge about callback and hell callback there is no problem.Ist thing is that call back and call back hell.For example:hell call back is like a we can store a class inside a class.As you heard about that nested in C, C++ language.Nested Means that a class inside a another class.

Comment: The answer will be more helpful if it contains code snippet to show what is 'Callback hell' and same code snippet with Rx after removing 'callback hell'