# call a callback in other callback js

Tags: javascript

I wondering if we can set a function containing a Callback function as parameter to another function who takes a callback too. 
Example

```
function save(err, data, cb){};

function get(id, cb){};
```

`get('12', save)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, a variable can be passed as argument of a function!
It may be clearer for you if you do:

```js
// This also works with the notation `function save(...)`
var save = function(err, data, cb) {
        alert('save' + err); // save12
    },
    get = function(id, cb) {
        alert('get' + id); // get12
        cb(id); // This call the "save" function
    }
;

get('12', save);
```

Just be careful to not stack your callback too much or you will enter in the [callback hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098066/what-is-callback-hell-and-how-and-why-rx-solves-it) world!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, check this example:

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/n1ssf5up/6/)

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {   
  function1({
       param: "1",
       callback: function () {
           function2({
               param : "2",
               callback: function(){
                   alert("hello");
               }
           })
       }
    });    
});

function function1(params){
    alert(params.param);
    params.callback();
}

function function2(params){
    alert(params.param);
    params.callback();
}
```

I hope it will be useful.