# Javascript: Calling a delayed function inside another delayed function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, delay

So, I have a delayed function called delayed1 that gets repeated everytime cond1 is true, the problem is, somewhere inside that delayed1 function do_something1() gets called and if cond3 is true, another delayed function called delayed2 gets called. 
Now the problem is I want delayed1 to wait until delayed2 is finished (that means until cond2 is false) and then resume again, which doesn't seem to be happening. Once delayed2 gets started, delayed1 doesn't wait for it to finish and then resume. Is there a way to do this? Hopefully I was clear enough...

```
function delayed2() {
    setTimeout(function () {
       do_something2();
        if ( cond2 ) {
            delayed2();
        }
    }, 1000)
}

function do_something1(){
    if ( cond3 ){
        delayed2();
    }
    else {
        something_else();
    }
}

function delayed1() {
    does_something_here();
    setTimeout(function () {
        do_something1();
        if ( cond1 ){
            delayed1();
        }
    }, 1000)

}
```

Comment: Could you guys elaborate a bit? Sorry, I just started learning js yesterday

Comment: _"Hopefully I was clear enough..."_ Not entirely, as interpret here. _"Sorry, I just started learning js yesterday"_ , _"My code is much more complex than I wrote in my example"_ ? Can create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to demonstrate ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I started learning js yesterday, but I know the basics of programming :)  And I'm not sure if stacksnippets would work, as I am using this code through Tampermonkey for a certain site.

Comment: Did you want to repeatedly run do_something2 and do_something_here and do_something1 every second?

Comment: Autocucumber is annoying

Comment: @Pred See also jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net , plnkr http://plnkr.co

Comment: @JaromandaX What is "Autocucumber" ?

Comment: @JaromandaX that is correct

Comment: @guest271314 auto correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using callbacks. Following is a basic representation:

```js
var count = 0;

function delay1(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Delay 1");
    count++;
    if (count < 12) {
      if (count % 2 == 0) {
        delay1();
      } else {
        delay2()
      }
    }
    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function delay2(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Delay 2");

    if (count > 10) {
      delay1(function() {
        console.log("This is callback;")
      })
    } else if (count % 2 == 0) {
      delay2();
    } else {
      delay1()
    }

    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
    count++;
  }, 1000);
}


delay1();
```

Comment: I used this as last resort, after trying the promises and Deferreds (unsuccessfully) and it worked exactly as I wanted it to, thanks a lot man :) Now if you're not a noob like me, I suggest using the 2 other solutions because they are more recommended and I'll have to learn using them myself, but I needed just a quick fix for this problem for now. Thanks again for your answer

Comment: I'm glad, I was able to help. Also I may be wrong but `promises` were invented because of a situation called as `callback hell`. You can refer [callbackhell](http://callbackhell.com/), [SO - Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098066/what-is-callback-hell-and-how-and-why-rx-solves-it)

Comment: Of course. Promises provide easy,short and novel mechanism to do what you do here with callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

I see what your are trying to do here. You may probably want to approach in a different way. The best way would be to use [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/) or [Deferreds](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/).

Here is the example using jquery deferreds of your given code.

```
var wait_a_second = $.Deffered();

$.when(wait_a_second)
    .then(does_something_here)
    .then(function(){
        if( cond1 ) delayed1();
    })

    .then(delayed1);


function delayed1(){
    var d = $.Deffered()

    // Your conditions and logic
    if( cond ) {
        d.resolve();
    }

    return d.promise();
}

function delayed2(){
    var d = $.Deffered();

    // Your conditions and logic
    if( cond ) {
        d.resolve();
    }

    return d.promise();
}
```

In short learn promises to manage async operations queue.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to implement synchronous execution in JS.

Promise is a mechanism which returns an object to which you can hook callbacks. These callbacks can be called once a specific function is done with execution. Here is how it applies to your situation.

You generally have 3 functions which depend on each other. The first one should wait for the second and the second one should wait for the third. In the first level the second function should return a `Promise`.

```
function delayed1() {

    does_something_here();

    setTimeout(function () {
        var promise = do_something1();

        promise.then(function(){
            if ( cond1 ){
               delayed1();
           }
        });

    }, 1000) 
}
```

Here is your second function. It creates a promise and returns it. Also inside its `if ( cond3 )` it should wait for a promise from the third function. I'm not going to write your third function as I'm certain that you can do it yourself following this pattern.

```
function do_something1(){

   return new Promise(function(resolve){
       if ( cond3 ){
           var promise = delayed(2);

           promise.then(function(){ 
              resolve()
            }) 

       }
       else {
          something_else();
          resolve();
       }    
   })  


}
```

Comment: So if I understood this correctly, I have to return another promise from the third function ( in this case called delayed2() ) and that should do the trick, right?

Comment: Shouldn't this do something then? https://jsfiddle.net/7esybcu9/
I know I did something wrong somewhere, I searched for promises online but just couldn't figure out a way to make them work in my particular case. Sorry

Comment: You have two problems there. One is that you don't run any function. Add `()` after the `delayed1` function. The other problem is that the `delayed2` function doesn't resolve anything. So, `promise.then` will never execute inside `do_something1`. Go through a promise tutorial (MDN) from the beginning. Do simple samples. Then build your case for two levels. Go for the 3rd level when you have good understanding about 2 level architecture.