# Promise chain not getting executing properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, requestjs

I've a promise chain in my nodejs code, I couldn't understand why the second 'then' part is being executed before the first 'then' part completes it execution. Can someone help me understand what is wrong with the below code.

```
    .then(model=>{
       return mongooseModel.find({})
              .then(result=>{
                return _.each(model.dataObj,data=>{
                       return _.each(data.fields,field=>{
                           if(_findIndex(result, {'field.type':'xxx'})>0)
                           {
                           return service.getResp(field.req) //this is a service that calls a $http.post
                                  .then((resp)=>{
                                        field.resp=resp;
                                        return field; 
                                     })      

                             }
                         })  
                      })
              })
              .then(finalResult=>{
                submit(finalResult); //this is being called before the then above is completely done
              }) 

    })

    function submit(finalResult){
     .....
    }
```

I've solved my problem by making the the changes as below

```
    .then(model=>{

                    return Promise.each(model.dataObj,data=>{
                           return getRequest(data.fields)
                           .then(()=>{
                           return service.getResp(field.req) //this is a service that calls a $http.post
                                      .then((resp)=>{
                                            field.resp=resp;
                                            return field; 
                                         })      

                           })
                    })                  
                  .then(finalResult=>{
                    submit(finalResult);                   
}) 

        })


        function getRequest(fields){

        return mongooseModel.find({})
                .then(result=>{
                if(_findIndex(result, {'field.type':'xxx'})>0)
                               {
                               }

                })
        }
```

Comment: This is one of the best examples of [callback hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098066/what-the-hell-is-callback-hell-and-how-and-why-rx-solves-it) I've seen in a while. Re-working your data architecture to be a little flatter might help debugging this and future issues.

Answer (score 1):

At least part of your problem is here:

```
.then(result=>{
    return _.each(model.dataObj,data=>{
```

You need to return a promise if you want the `.then` below to wait for its completion. Currently you are returning the result of `_.each`, which is not a promise (`_.each` is not asynchronous), so the next `.then` just continues right away. You eventually do return what looks like a promise from `service.getResp`, but you are returning it to the `_.each` function, which doesn't do anything useful with it.

You should probably do your loops to find the `field.req` that you need, and return the promise outside of the loops. Something like:

```
.then(result => {
  let req;

  // Loop and find what you need (maybe refactor this into a function)
  // _.each ...
  //    _.each ...

  // Outside of the loops return the promise
  return service.getResp(req)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I'll try to modify my code to return a promise after the loop.