# My Promise going into both then and catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox

I have a set of nested promises shown below. The expected behaviour here is for 1 to be printed, then 2 to be printed and then for the callback to be called under `dropbox_functions.moveFolder('test', data.ui)`. However what is happening is that 1 is printed then 2 is printed and the 2.1 is printed, so the 2 promise is going into the `then` and the `catch`. I cant work out why.

```
dropbox_functions.createBatchFolder(data.ui)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log('1')
          console.log(response)
          dropbox_functions.checkScannerFolderExists('test')  
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log('2')
              console.log(response)
              dropbox_functions.moveFolder('test', data.ui)
                .then(function(response) {
                  console.log(response)
                  callback(null, data)
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
                  callback('Data not copied from scanner', data)
                });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('2.1')
                console.log(response)
                dropbox_functions.createDataFolder(data.ui)
                  .then(function(response) {                      
                    console.log(response)
                    callback('No scanned folder', data)
                  })
                  .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    callback('Data Folder not created', data)
                  });  
            });
            // callback(null, data)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('1.2')
          console.log(error)
          callback('Folder not created', data)
        });
```

Comment: Why are you nesting your promises? That’s the whole point of promises avoiding a callback hell

Comment: This means that `dropbox_functions.moveFolder('test', data.ui)` generated an exception. Instead of doing `console.log('2.1')` it would be more useful to do `console.log('2.1', error)` so you know what the exception is.

Comment: You can create different promises and call then to resolve each promise and use 1 catch to resolve the errors. That does cause the issue of not knowing where the error occurred but in that case you can switch to async/await

Comment: `dropbox_functions.moveFolder` is the reason of your error. Either the function is not available or `data.ui` is unavailable

Comment: The way you have it set up one of the catches acts as a pass through. So it catches an error but then carries on resolving

Comment: could you explain how you do 1 catch for all the promises

Comment: and what do you mean by one catch acts as a pass through

Comment: Have you printed the error yet? (see my previous comment)

Comment: yes i printed the error and it was coming from the moveFolder which wasnt returning a promise thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be an error thrown, after execution of line `console.log('2')`. If an error thrown within a promise execution, the next immediate catch block will catch the particular error.

```
              console.log('2')
              console.log(response) <-- Here 
              dropbox_functions.moveFolder('test', data.ui) <--- Here 
                .then(function(response) {
                  console.log(response)
                  callback(null, data)
                })
                .catch(function(error) { <-- or here
                  console.log(error);
                  callback('Data not copied from scanner', data)
                });
```

Comment: movefolder was not returning a promise which was causing the error and i have now fixed that and it works thank you

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an answer but an recommendation. The whole point of promises is that you don't have to nest them, but can [chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) them instead. This is done by simply returning a new promise as return value of the function provided to *then*. You can then chain another *then* statement after it that handles the newly resolved promise.

```
dropbox_functions
  .createBatchFolder(data.ui)
  .then(function (response) { // response of createBatchFolder 
    console.log('1');
    console.log(response);
    return dropbox_functions.checkScannerFolderExists('test');
  })
  .then(function (response) { // response of checkScannerFolderExists
    console.log('2');
    console.log(response);
    return dropbox_functions.moveFolder('test', data.ui);
  })
  .then(function (response) { // response of moveFolder
    console.log(response);
    callback(null, data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) { // some error occurred
    console.error(error);
    callback(error, data);
  });
```

If you need to do something for specific errors you can check the `name` and/or `description` properties of the error or convert it to a string by calling `toString()` on it.

---

Furthermore by calling a callback function yourself you still introduce [callback hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098066/what-is-callback-hell-and-how-and-why-rx-solves-it) into your program. I'd recommend returning a promise instead and work with that. If the code above is the last statement of your function you can simply return a resolved promise from the last *then* statement.

```
function yourFunction() {
  // ...
  return dropbox_functions
    .createBatchFolder(data.ui)
    // ...
    .then(function (response) { // response of moveFolder
      console.log(response);
      return Promise.resolve([null, data]);
    })
    .catch(function (error) { // some error occurred
      console.error(error);
      return Promise.reject([error, data]);
    });
}
```

If it's not the last statement simply save the resulting promise into a variable and return that after you did you other stuff. You could even leave out the *catch* statement if all you do is forward it into `Promise.reject(...)` (this is currently not the case since you add `data` too). This can then be handled by the code calling *yourFunction*.