# Node js serial http requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https, request

I need to make 2 http request - the response of the first one will be used in the second. The way I do the request is using the `http.get(url, callback)` method from the **http** module. But I assume nodejs spawns another thread for the second http request and responses arrive asynchronously. What I did is it to put the second http request in the callback of the first, it works, but looks like unmaintainable code to me.

Any other ways to do it?

Comment: Try `async` http://caolan.github.io/async/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid long nesting of asynchronous functions in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234619/how-to-avoid-long-nesting-of-asynchronous-functions-in-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but just reiterating what Dhaval Soni said. If you have `async / await` syntax at your disposal, then the easiest solution is the following:

```
// inside "async" function

const asyncResult1 = await requestPromise(`${rootUrl}/posts/1`)

const asyncResult2 = await requestPromise(`${rootUrl}/albums/${asyncResult1.id}`)
```

Notice how the result of the first async request is used to make the second async request.

Comment: Also, @Niezborala's response doesn't answer OP's question, which is about serial requests, not parallel requests (which is what `Promise.all` is for).

Answer (score 1):

I made for you quick example in `ES6`:

```
const requestPromise = require('request-promise');

const rootUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

const request1 = requestPromise(`${rootUrl}/posts/1`);
const request2 = requestPromise(`${rootUrl}/albums/1`);

Promise.all([request1, request2])
  .then(values => {
    console.log(values);
  });
```

You need to install two dependencies:

```
"request": "^2.78.0",
"request-promise": "^4.1.1"
```